# Dividir clases con parametros con Java

Tags: java, clase, arraylist

Tengo este código que llama un archivo `txt`, lo almacena en un `ArrayList`, y finalmente desordenada y ordena todos los caracteres del mismo.

```
public static void main (String args []) throws IOException{
   String linea = "PALABRA2.TXT";
   ArrayList<String> archivoLista = new ArrayList<>();
   try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  FileReader("Archivo.txt")))  {
        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(linea);
            archivoLista.add(linea); /* Agrega la Línea leída a la lista */
        }
   }
   System.out.println("LISTA DESORDENADA: ");
   Collections.shuffle(archivoLista); /* Modifica Orden*/
   /* Imprimir en una sola línea */
   for(String temp: archivoLista){    
      System.out.println(temp); 
   }
   /* Ordenar nuevamente*/
   System.out.println("LISTA ORDENADA: ");
   Collections.sort(archivoLista);
   for(String temp: archivoLista){
    System.out.println(temp);
   }
 }
}
```

Lo que quiero es mejorar el diseño del código. Alguien de acá me aconsejó dividir cada función en diferentes clases.

Necesito que la primera con el metodo `main` muestre el archivo `txt` en un `Arraylist`, la segunda reciba ese `List<String>` y lo desordene, y finalmente la tercera lo reciba y ordene nuevamente.

El tema es que no se como se realiza para que las clases tenga como parametro el `arrayList` del `main`. Y así realicen el ordenamiento y desordenamiento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso tener una clase para desordenar u ordenar una lista no me parece necesario ya que no estas haciendo más que invocar a `Collections.shuffle` y `Collections.sort`, y esto no me parece responsabilidad/comportamiento suficiente como para construir una clase.

Si en el futuro aparecieran en tus requerimientos otras formas de desordenar u ordenar quizá si tenga sentido tener una clase con la responsabilidad de ordenar colecciones y otra para desordenar.

En este caso sería mejor simplemente tener una única clase, separar las 3 acciones en 3 métodos de dicha clase para poder invocar parte de la lógica de tu programa por separado y desde otros puntos de un sistema.

Aún así, respondiendo puntualmente a tu consulta:

> . El tema es que no se como se realiza para que las clases tenga como parametro el arrayList del main. Y así realicen el ordenamiento y desordenamiento.

Una posible solución podría ser la siguiente:

**Lectura de archivo y creación de lista:**

```
 public class TextFileReader {

    private List<String> readFromFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        ArrayList<String> archivoLista = new ArrayList<>();
        String linea = "";
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))){
            while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                archivoLista.add(linea); 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(archivoLista.toString());
        return archivoLista;
    }
 }
```

**Métodos de desordenamiento de listas:**

```
public class Shuffler {
    public void shuffle(List<String> list){
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }

    /*
     * More shuffle methods..
     */
}
```

**Métodos de ordenamiento de listas:**

```
public class Sorter {

    public void sort(List<String> list){
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list.toString());

    }

    /*
     * More sort methods..
     */
}
```

**Clase principal**, instanciación e invocación de las clases anteriores:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main (String args []) throws IOException{
            TextFileReader test = new TextFileReader();
            Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
            Shuffler shuffler = new Shuffler();
            List<String> archivoLista = test.readFromFile("src/Archivo.txt");
            shuffler.shuffle(archivoLista);
            sorter.sort(archivoLista);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. No se si es necesario dividirlo en clases, pero al momento de realizar el Testing se me complica con cada metodo. Por eso no se si es lo más conveniente.